# Is there a succinct way of performing an identical coalesce on all columns of an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, coalesce

Say I have a query:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Sex, Age FROM Human
```

If for any reason there's a null in the table for a value we can:

```
coalesce(FirstName, 'Unknown')
```

For larger queries with far more columns, instead of coalescing each column individually is there a way to coalesce each individual column, but without duplicating the amount of `coalesce` operations?

Something like this:

```
SELECT coalesce(FirstName, LastName, Sex, Age, 'Unknown') FROM Human
```

(I know that's wrong and wont work, it's part of my example trying to illustrate my intentions).

Ideally the above would check each column in-turn and replace any nulls with 'Unknown'. Is there an easy way of doing that rather than this:

```
SELECT coalesce(FirstName,'Unknown'), coalesce(LastName,'Unknown'), coalesce(Sex, 'Unspecified'), coalesce(Age,'0') FROM Human
```

Also, going back to this example:

```
SELECT coalesce(FirstName, LastName, Sex, Age, 'Unknown') FROM Human
```

Is there a way of applying an over-arching `coalesce` like the above, except for n amount of columns? For example only for `FirstName`,`LastName` and `Sex`, not for the rest.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Well, NULL means *unknown* :-) Btw, when you use coalesce on a numeric column you should use a string for the unknown value: `coalesce(Age,'0')` should be `coalesce(Age,0)`

Comment: To your final question, COALESCE takes as many arguments as you want.

Comment: @dnoeth, `NULL` doesn't mean anything

Comment: @Jodrell: Well, that's breaking news, tell this E.F. Codd :-)

Comment: Of course I ment: you should **not** use a string for the unknown value: `coalesce(Age,'0')` should be `coalesce(Age,0)` And antoher of course, the age is no longer unknown then :-)

Comment: `NULL` might mean something in the context of a certain column in a specific query.

Comment: @Jodrell: NULL is a *representation of "missing information and inapplicable information"* see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: No, this is why you use `DEFAULT` values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Then how do you default an `age` or a `gender` or a `last_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) "is a syntactic shortcut for the `CASE` expression."

The questions you should ask yourself are,

1. Why do I have these `NULL` values in the first place?
2. Why am I handling the presentation of my data in my TSQL? TSQL is a great tool for retrieving relational data using set based operations. TSQL is bad tool for making your data look nice.
3. What would substituting `NULL` with `'Unknown'` give me, apart from a performance deficit and headaches down the road?